# How to add Javascript function to every object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering how can I attach a function to be available for each object on the page. I know that I can do it like this:

```
mything = {
    init: function(SELECTOR){

    },
    destroy: function(){

    }
};
```

But then it is available to me only this way: `mything.init(SELECTOR);`

What I want is to be able to do the same thing this way:

```
$('.mydiv, input, whatever').myFunction({ 'my' : 'arg', 'my2' : 'arg2' });
$('.mydiv').myFunction('destroy');
```

I know that there are plenty of Javascript tutorials out there but I don't know how to search for this type of functionality. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You dont seem to want to extend _every_ object (a crazy idea). You seem to only want to extend _jQuery objects_ (a good idea). That is a very important distinction.

Comment: @AlexWayne You're right! Apologies for my mistake.

Comment: the first function seems like a custom selector. It's possible to extend the selectors that can be used to also include your own custom build selection logic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, it looks like it is just enough for you to extend the `jQuery.prototype`.

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn, mything );
```

However, it is of course possible, even if not very recommendable, to go that ultimate root and extend the `Object.prototype`. This *really* would add those functions to every and each object.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I'm looking for :) I just wanted to know where to look for more information and now I know that I should seek for `prototype`.

Comment: it would add it to _almost_ any object hoist objects are not required to have Object as the prototype. E.g. console in IE9 does not have object as it's prototype

Comment: @RuneFS: you're right. Also self-defining objects created by `Object.create( null )` wouldn't be affected.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't necessarily a great idea (it's a terrible idea), but you can accomplish this with prototypes:

```
Object.prototype.myFunction = function() {
  console.log('Called myFunction');
};
```

And you can see what happens for an arbitrary object:

```
document.myFunction();
```

Note that adding to the prototypes of classes other than your own (and especially the builtin objects or classes belonging to libraries other than your own) can induce lots of confusion. This is one of the reasons why Google's own style guide [recommends against this](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml#Modifying_prototypes_of_builtin_objects) (despite much temptation to add String.startsWith, String.endsWith, and many other useful operations to builtin types).

Answer (score 1):

The *clean* way to do what you describe is to wrap your code inside a jQuery plugin.

Here is the official [jquery plugin guide](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring). Read through it, it is actually quite simple to understand.

The part about wrapping functions (so that `$(selector).myFunction()` calls `init`, `$(selector).myFunction('doThis')` calls `doThis`, etc...) is [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Plugin_Methods).